# Using default credentials to call api in console app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to call a Web API 2 method that requires auth from a console app running on my desktop where I have authorization, but I'm getting 401 Unathorized. I know I have authorization because when I make the same call from a web browser it works fine. So a browser can get my default login id/pw to send to the API but .NET's WebClient can't? That seems insane. There has to be a way to do this without entering my id/pw into the console app.

The below is what I'm using in a console app and it's not working.

This is using Windows Auth as it's intranet stuff.

This throws an exception "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

```
using(var c = new WebClient())
{
    c.UseDefaultCredentials = true;   
    string value = c.DownloadString("http://localhost:62659/api/Store/GetData");
}
```

I also tried the below and when I mouse over DefaultNetworkCredentials the username/pw are blank strings. Why wouldn't .NET be able to figure this out?

```
using(var c = new WebClient())
            {
                var creds = new CredentialCache();
                var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:62659/api/Store/GetData");
                creds.Add(uri, "ntlm", System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
                c.Credentials = creds;
                string value = c.DownloadString(uri);
            }
```

Comment: Are you receiving an exception or any error information you could share?

Comment: Fiddler2 will show you the credentials being passed with the get request.

Comment: I use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for troubleshooting this type of problems.

Comment: Are you able to view your credential information and compare it between the two different calls while monitoring your network traffic?

Comment: So are the comments telling me this should work and it works for others?

Comment: Update question with a new way of doing it and it's showing DefaultNetworkCredentials object as having blank username/password. So the core of it is why doesn't .NET know my windows id/pw but Chrome does and how can I get .NET to know these automatically? I mean .NET is a windows framework, you'd think it knows this stuff.

Comment: Do you have your login information stored in your Credential Manager? It is likely that Chrome has your credential information saved, but you do not have that information saved within Windows. Check for that credential in `Control Panel > Credential Manger`.

Comment: @gmiley Wow I've never seen that before but no there is nothing there. So this would make sense but is this the only way to do this? When I go to have this ran on the server this won't be set on there. I find in my console app I can do WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; to the windows ID but is there a way for pw or to use this information for web request.

Comment: None that I am aware of. That is the purpose of the Credential Manager, to safely store your password protected credential within the system. Other applications can store credentials that you have typed in within that application. I will add this as an answer and maybe try to expand on it a little bit if this was a help for you.

Comment: @gmiley I can't remember, but this would imply that when I change my AD pw and try to access an intranet site from Chrome that needs auth it would prompt me for id/pw and once I do it saves it? Man this makes using console apps to make API calls in a corp environment basically a no go which is really sad. No admins will want to maintain the Credential Manager when batch server login id/pw changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that you do not have your credential information stored within [Windows Credential Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can access that via `Control Panel > Credential Manager`. From there you can add whatever credential you need. `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` and `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` contains the login credentials of the currently logged-in or impersonated user. If what you are connecting to requires different credentials then these will not work. You will need to add those credentials to the Credential Manager in Windows.

The reason you are connecting fine within Chrome is that Chrome will store credentials within itself that you have designated to save.

Login credentials being used as functional ids can be set to never expire, or it will need to be added to a list of monthly/yearly maintenance items to update the password for those accounts.

You would also want to handle bad login information within your application. If this is an automated task, have it email or otherwise notify someone that the credentials need to be updated.

If a user runs this, you could simply prompt the current user to provide a new password, which you can use to update the stored credentials right then.

Another option would be to set the user running the application as a user on the receiving end using those same credentials. That way the entire process is tied to the user(s) that will be running the application.

Comment: This is a big bummer. In a corp setting where apps run from a batch server, admins aren't going to want to maintain this when they change the batch id/pw (which we don't know as we make jobs in a scheduling system). Big bummer.

Comment: @user441521 - I mentioned a little about that after I saw your comment above. Another approach would be to write this into your application. If the credential fails due to bad login information, you could have it email out, or otherwise notify someone, that the credentials need to be updated.

Comment: @user441521 - I have expanded my answer more to, hopefully, provide some alternatives.

Comment: @user441521 - Did any of this help you out at all with answering your question?

Comment: This would be called from a scheduling system so it'll only be 1 user that the admins maintain. I don't think there is anyway around this. I'll most likely just create a console app that hits the DB directly using Windows Auth and have it do the same sql stuff the API was doing.

Comment: @user441521 - It would be something you could discuss with your network admins, but a lot of people/companies, that i have had this discussion with, that use this design in an automated setup - set the accounts being used to never expire. They are then added to a list of accounts and can be added to a plan to change their password as part of the admins scheduled maintenance plans instead of running with the possibility of an account expiring in the middle of the day, or worse middle of the night.

Answer (score 1):

Using DefaultCredentials should work to use Windows Auth from console application. As long as you have the appropriate authorization header that your web api is looking for. Same with my comment I recommend testing the api call using Postman so that you can troubleshoot and check what you are missing.

Regarding the credentials as blank, this is maybe because you are using DefaultNetworkCredentials.

Try this:

```
using(var c = new WebClient())
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:62659/api/Store/GetData");
    c.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    string value = c.DownloadString(uri);
}
```

If you want to use NetworkCredential you should be inputting network credentials like so:

```
c.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
```

I created this type of console application and used it as a service and I can tell you that this should work. You should just need to troubleshoot and bits by bits get the real problem.

Comment: What's the difference between NetworkCredential and DefaultCredentials? I mean my ID, which would be DefaultCredentials I think, is an AD id on the network. Sadly by place doesn't allow me to run Postman. Trying fiddler but not seeing the traffic come up, but I don't use fiddler all that much so it's probably me. Trying. And your Web API was Web API 2 with Authorize tag on controllers and using Windows authentication?

Comment: Fiddler doesn't show this when it's coming from the console app it seems.

Comment: @user441521 - `DefaultNetworkCredentials` is of the type `NetworkCredential` which is the actual class that is used. `DefaultCredentials` returns objects of the type: `ICredentials`, however the `GetCredential()` function on `DefaultCredentials` returns an object of the type `NetworkCredential`. Regardless of which one you use, you are actually working with `NetworkCredential` instances which implements the `ICredentials` interface.

Comment: Yes I am using Web API2 using Windows Auth.

Comment: Not 100% sure what I'm looking for in fiddler but was able to get it to show up if I add .fiddler to the url. When I look at the headers under cookies/login I see: Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication, WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, WWW-Authenticate: NTLM. When I look at the request from the web browser under headers->Cookies/Login it says: Persistent-Auth: true

Comment: Fiddler has a composer tab which allows me to make the call from there. It has an Automatically Authenticate option. I check that and run this url and get the same 401. It's Auth tab says: Authorization Header (Negotiate) appears to contain a Kerberos ticket: and then some hex stuff

Comment: You can also try to add request.PreAuthenticate = true; This is a good [read](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/feb/18/net-webrequestpreauthenticate-not-quite-what-it-sounds-like.) and may help you with

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/feb/18/net-webrequestpreauthenticate-not-quite-what-it-sounds-like